# Swift - Missing argument for parameter 'host' in call

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my code:

```
func submitLacunaRequest (#module: String, method: String, parameters: AnyObject, completion: (responseObject: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> (Void)) -> NSURLSessionTask? {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com").URLByAppendingPathComponent(module)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json-rpc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Missing argument for parameter "host" in call.
It happens at this line.

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com").URLByAppendingPathComponent(module)
```

Any ideas how to solve this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That eror is missleading. The problem isn't a missing parameter, but how you access the `NSURL`. You either have to add an `?` to access the optional, because the `NSURL` can be null, or you unwrap it:

```
//First option:
let url = NSURL(string: "https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com")?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(module)

//Unwrapping
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com")?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(module){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json-rpc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
}
```